# Can I enable/disable wake timers on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, c++, power-management

I know that one can enable or disable wake timers on Windows Vista and later OS using [PowerWriteACValueIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or PowerWriteDCValueIndex APIs with the `GUID_ALLOW_RTC_WAKE` or `{BD3B718A-0680-4D9D-8AB2-E1D2B4AC806D}` from the `GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP` or `{238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20}`
How do I do the same in **Windows XP**?

Comment: The bottom of this MSDN page describes the mapping between XP and Vista+ functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, I found it too. But that doesn't explain how to do what I want. Now I'm wondering if it's even supported by Windows XP?